# Contribute a Ionic 3 App to F-Droid

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, fdroid

I'd like to contribute to the F-Droid GitLab Repo.

I followed this guide: https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroiddata/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

I have done this already, many times with a normal native app. That worked great. But with an Ionic app it seems to be different. I see, for example, no gradle data in my Ionic app. Do I need gradle? Because the build failed because he can not run gradle clean ..

Heres my stack:

> ==== detail begin ==== FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'clean' not found in root project.

This is how my metadata file looks like:

```
Categories:System
License:GPL-3.0
```

[...]

```
Repo Type:git
Repo:<Repo Link>

Build:1.0,1
    commit=<commit>
    gradle=yes

Auto Update Mode:None
Update Check Mode:None
```

Everything in <> is filled out correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forging new ground here!  We (F-Droid) don't have solid support for Cordoba/Ionic/etc.  but the only thing preventing it is someone doing the work!  We're working on adding a new build field `sudo=` which will let you download and install whatever you need to run your build.  I've never used Ionic, Cordoba, or any of these Javascript app things, so I don't know the details.

You can follow the progress of `sudo=` here:
https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidserver/merge_requests/297

It'll still be a while yet before this is deployed on our infrastructure, but your testing it will speed up that process!

Comment: The linked MR is merged by now. Is there an update for Ionic-support in F-Droid?